# RemoveClass from multiple pages

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Is it possible to use jquery to removeClass from elements on multiple pages within the same file?

```html
<html>

 <script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>  

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("div.mydiv").click(function(){
$("img").removeClass("border_blue"),
$("img").addClass("border_red");
   });
});
</script>

<style>
.border_blue {border: 3px solid blue;}
.border_red {border: 6px dashed red;}
</style>

</body>

<img class="border_blue" src="img/mypic.png">

<div class="mydiv"> I'm Not Blue </div>

</body>
</html>
```

the following data is on multiple pages: mypics1.html, mypics2.html, etc

```html
<img class="border_blue" src="mypic.jpg">
```

Comment: One possible way, is to put the handling in a javascript file, and then add a `<script>` element to the related pages that need the file.

Comment: 1) Your HTML is all sorts of malformed. I suggest you start with some [fundamental tutorials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML). 2) What do you mean by _"multiple pages within the same file"_? 3) Does your code not work? What does it do instead? Are there any errors reported in the console?

Comment: I ask yall overook my beginer-errors., i am here to learn and I appreciate the links --- I have multple pages with images with 'blue borders', how can i call the function on page one and activate it onto all other images on all other pages. My knowledge is obviously limited, and Ive research Pauls 'handling' comment, but nothing that I understand. I am unaware of the use of the console, since I handtype all my script.  A simple example with a nudge (or a shove) into the right direction would do me wonders.

Comment: Should the state change apply to just the current session (until the page is closed), the current visitor (forever) or all visitors?

Comment: ahh, didnt think of that, I would be happy at this point to keep it active until the page closes, even though im guessing the use of cookies somehow would be required to keep it active over a long period. Im eger to learn, but the lanugage gap is my major difficulty.

Comment: I take it you don't have any server-side capabilities that could help with this?

Comment: oh i wish i knew how to route this through a server, but the anser is no, I do not

Answer (score 0):

First, you really don't need jQuery for something like this. The vanilla JS solution is barely any longer and you won't need to include an entire extra library.

It sounds like you want to *persist* some state and refer to it on all pages. For that you can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

You can write a script in a file and include that in any page where you need it. For example

```html
<script src="scripts/img-border-toggle.js" defer></script>
```

The script can then provide a function to toggle the classes, an event listener to set the state, and a check to see if the toggle should occur immediately.

```js
// file: scripts/img-border-toggle.js

const TOGGLE_STATE_KEY = 'TOGGLE_STATE';

const toggleImageBorders = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('img.border_blue').forEach((img) => {
    img.classList.remove('border_blue');
    img.classList.add('border_red');
  });
};

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.closest('div.myDiv')) {
    localStorage.setItem(TOGGLE_STATE_KEY, 'true');
    toggleImageBorders();
  }
});

if (localStorage.getItem(TOGGLE_STATE_KEY) === 'true') {
  toggleImageBorders();
}
```

Comment: well ty, i will study this and how to apply it to my needs. i appreciate your efforts.

Comment: works like a charm across all pages that are linked to the .js - thankyou  only issue is that it loads on boot (or refesh) and isnt clickable. I tried added  onclick="toggleImageBorders()" onto a button, without success.

Comment: @Gonzo what isn't clickable? If you want the function to do something other than remove `border_blue` and add `border_red`, you'd need to use something else

Comment: yes, can the function be triggered on demand by clicking on a div/text/etc instead of triggered by loading the page?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. Isn't the entire premise of this post that you wanted to click once and have the state persist? If that is not the case, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77938225/edit) to explain properly exactly what you _do_ want to happen